# Is there a way to check if <string.h> is included?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm creating a header only library and I wanted to check if the user has defined <string.h> so that I can use memcpy. I read online about how libraries like stdio have guard macros, but I couldn't find one for string.h. Any ideas? Or is there a way just to see if memcpy is a function?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `#include <string.h>` for yourself?  Or just forward declare `void *memcpy(void *, const void *, size_t);` at the top of the source file you need it in?

Comment: I guess I've just never heard of anyone having code paths that operated conditionally based on what the caller included.  Is this a "header only" library you are putting together?

Comment: @selbie yeah, it is a header only a library, so I my reasoning was that I should keep it as light as possible.

Comment: **Any ideas?** simply `#include <string.h>`. There will be no problem if users of your library also include it on their own. **Or is there a way just to see if memcpy is a function?** No, not by the pre-processor.

Comment: @pmg Alright I see. I'll just include <string.h>. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from my aversion to header only libraries, I don't agree with your reasoning. This is an over-optimization. Probably the best hybrid solution you can do is to just use memcpy without explicitly adding a `#include <string.h>`.  Any developer worth his salt that includes your library will figure it out if he gets an error saying memcpy is undeclared.  None of this changes my opinion that you are over-optimizing and only making your code harder to maintain.  **Just include <string.h>**

Comment: @selbie yeah I got it. Thanks again!

Comment: @selbie I wouldn't declare it yourself, as there might be subtleties you get different (and thus wrong). Just including it (yet again) is right though.

Comment: @Deduplicator - agree.

Comment: can you pls untick my answer

Comment: @CEPB Yes, I just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can portably tell if `string.h` has **not** been included.

Per [**7.24.1 String function conventions**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.1p1) of the (draft) C11 standard:

> The header `<string.h>` declares one type and several functions, and defines one macro useful for manipulating arrays of character type and other objects treated as arrays of character type. The type is `size_t` and the macro is `NULL` ...

If `NULL` is **not** defined, then the user could not have included `string.h` prior to including your header(s).

I see no portable way of definitively determining if `string.h` **has** been included.

Comment: WOW good one, but hold on what do you mean (draft), that means its not in C11 standard?

Comment: @CEPB That's a link to a copy of the final draft C11 standard - one of the few available.  Links to the actual standard don't exist AFAICT - copies of the actual standard are not free and I suspect they're licensed/sold with restrictions against posting the contents.  As that's the *final* draft, it's likely identical to the actual C11 standard but I haven't done any real checking.  AFAIK no one has noted any differences from the actual C11 standard.

Comment: uh did not know that you have to pay for those :(

Comment: @CEPB See [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/10147399). Final drafts are free and often good enough for educational use. You don't need to pay for the standard unless you're implementing a compiler or similar.

Comment: That's where my "confusion" lays, do `GCC` and `Clang` (GNU Project and LLVM) pay those fees.

Comment: @CEPB they probably do. I don't have any inside knowledge on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `<string.h>`, include it yourself. You can also forward-declare `memcpy` and use it without including anything:

```
void* memcpy( void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count );
```

Comment: its header only library. so if I understand correctly there is no .c file

Comment: @CEPB then, they should go with forward declaration or should include `string.h` as any non-trivial project is going to include that anyway.

Comment: Your answer is fine for me. I gave you up. I know the best way is to include it. I just did not want you go get penalized.

Comment: @CEPB thank you for the feedback. I removed that part of the answer.